# User info stored in firebase firestore database in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-jetpack-compose

So I tried to follow and implement the firebase authentication method using a few articles and tutorials but have not been successful. I have been doing this in compose which seems to be quite different from doing this in xml. I am looking for registration, in which the user will add their credentials (name, e-mail and password) to a registration screen. This in turn is saved in firebase firestore database, how can I acheive this ?

https://gyazo.com/9690c5db059c3f95700169326c35b1dc

This is how we did it in xml:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val usersRef = rootRef.collection("users")
val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
auth.currentUser?.apply {
    usersRef.document(uid).set(mapOf(
        "Name" to Name,
        "Password" to pass,
        "email" to email,
        "uid" to uid
    )).addOnCompleteListener{ task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            Log.d("TAGI", "User successfully added.")
        } else {
            Log.d("TAGS", task.exception!!.message!!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? besides that, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) and this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8) might help.

Comment: This code is taken from my previous projects made in XML. I want to make something similar but in jetpack compose. This is what I am trying to do: https://gyazo.com/6f06df1451c8535842679e00cf26f790

Comment: I tried to follow both your resources but the first one shows a anonymous authentication where the user can sign in without the need to register + without any text fields to fill in the information. The other resource works well with the use of google account sign in but does not have a way to take user info such as name, telefonnumber, e-mail, pass etc and save it into a firestore database!

Comment: You can get from the FirebaseUser object only the available data.

Comment: Im sorry but I dont understand. So there is no way to register users data into firestore database ?

Comment: Yes, there is. The second resource explains that too.

Comment: ok will go through it again.